# Tabs with Vue in Laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm using Laravel and trying to get a Vue instance of tabs going, but for some reason the only thing showing is Tab 1 and Tab 2 but no content, and the tabs aren't clickable links or anything.

Is this just an issue with the way I'm calling Vue? It's natively installed on laravel 5.8 and I"m using it elsewhere with no problems

```
<div id="tabs" class="container">
<div class="tabs">
    <a v-on:click="activetab=1" v-bind:class="[ activetab === 1 ? 'active' : '' ]">Tab 1</a>
    <a v-on:click="activetab=2" v-bind:class="[ activetab === 2 ? 'active' : '' ]">Tab 2</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div v-if="activetab === 1" class="tabcontent">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Available At:</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach ($result as $id => $item)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $id }}</td>
                    @foreach($item as $subitem)
                    @if($subitem->name == "Task Title")
                        <td>{{ $subitem->task_comment }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $subitem->task_typet_id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $subitem->available_at }}</td>
                    @endif
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div v-if="activetab === 2" class="tabcontent">
        TEST
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
export default {
    el: '#tabs',
    data: { activetab: 1 },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#tabs',
  data() {
    return {
      activetab: 1
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="tabs" class="container">
  <div class="tabs">
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="activetab = 1" :class="[ activetab === 1 ? 'active' : '' ]">Tab 1</a>
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="activetab = 2" :class="[ activetab === 2 ? 'active' : '' ]">Tab 2</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div v-if="activetab === 1" class="tabcontent">
      TEST 1
    </div>
    <div v-if="activetab === 2" class="tabcontent">
      TEST 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your hyperlinks are set to use array syntax.  You should probably change it to:

```
<div class="tabs"> 
    <a v-on:click="activetab=1" v-bind:class="{ active: activetab === 1}">Tab 1</a> 
    <a v-on:click="activetab=2" v-bind:class="{ active: activetab === 2}">Tab 2</a> 
</div>
```